# Regex to get rid of everything past the first sentence in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to get rid of everything after the first dot (if there is more than 1 sentence), but at the same time, cases like e.g. have to be omited.

> Some line e.g., when people do something. Extra content.
>
> Some line (some parenthesis). Extra content.

I need to get rid of the "Extra content.". The returning value should be:

> Some line e.g., when people do something.
>
> Some line (some parenthesis).

So far I've come with this regex taken from other threads, but it only finds the dots and split the string into an array.

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\.)\.(?!(\s|$|\,|\w\.))/','',$text);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What if `e.g.` is followed by a space?

Comment: since this are results from a dictionary api, it always comes with a comma. Even if it doesn't come with a comma, i can str_replace('e.g. ','e.g.,',$string) before applying the regex.

Comment: In that case, can you just search for `". "`? No regex needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is try to match a dot, a space and a capital letter. This is probably the most reliable way to get you the start of a sentence.

```
<?php
    $text = 'Some line e.g., when people do something. Extra content.';
    echo preg_replace('/\.\s[A-Z](.+)/', '.', $text);
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/QYosLL

Comment: Works great! What would be the difference between preg_replace('/\.\s[\w](.+)/','.',$text); and preg_replace('/\.\s[\A-Z](.+)/','.',$text); ?

Comment: @andufo with Xeon06's answer you make sure that after the dot there is a capital letter \w include lower case and other characters. +1 Xeon06, good answer.

Comment: only problem is that this assumes "Extra Content" to be another 'regular' sentence...

Comment: @andufo, just like SeRPRo said, mine will only match capital letters while yours would also match lower-case letters.

Comment: @CrayonViolent as hard as I could think, I could not come up with a sentence starting with anything else than a capital letter.

Comment: @Xeon06: well for normal sentences/paragraphs/writing, I'd agree with you, but "extra content" is an arbitrary label and we don't really know the full extent of its definition. Could be multiple lines followed by more regular stuff, or random stuff like something in brackets, who knows?  Just sayin'...

Comment: @CrayonViolent indeed, it's good to mention. We can't really do anything without more details though.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the e.g. with a lookbehind.. something like this

```
preg_replace("#(?<=\w{2})\..*$#", ".", "Some line e.g., when people do something. Extra content.", -1, $count);
```

What I did is just look if there are 2 or more "word" characters before the dot.

[Example](http://xrg.es/?3730962642)

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 10

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\.( |$)/', '.',  $text);
```

This will replace the first dot followed by a space or end of line by a dot.

Comment: you use / as delim but don't escape it in your pattern.  On that note, you have a / in your pattern (and an extra match-all dot) for no apparent reason.  Also function syntax is wrong. 2nd argument is what you would replace with, 3rd argument is the subject.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: I'd made a mixture between perl s/// and php. Corrected.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: OK, thanks. May be be it's time for a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('~\.( |$)~','.',$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^
 (
   ([\w\(\)\,]+ ?) #word charakters, parenteses, kommas 
   |e\.g\.         # or e.g.s add more exceptions here
 )+                #multiple times
 \.                #final dot
 ( .*)?            #the optional extra stuff
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=\.)\s*[A-Z].*$/', '', $subject);
```

line by line to these lines :

```
Some line e.g., when people do something.

Some line e.g., when people do something. Extra content e.g.

Some line (some parenthesis). Extra content.
```

You get this:

```
Some line e.g., when people do something.

Some line e.g., when people do something.

Some line (some parenthesis).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will give you exactly what you want, sadly - right now I can only write this in python, not in PHP - though I am sure that regex will be almost the same and you will only need to rewrite the part for getting named groups. Basically, in Python I would do something like this:

```
import re

string = "Some line e.g., when people do something. Extra content."
regex = "([A-Z].+?\.)\s?[A-Z]"

m = re.search(regex, string)
```

Then, `m.group(0)` prints the whole catch:

```
'Some line e.g., when people do something. E'
```

and `m.group(1)` prints first catched group, which hopefully is exactly what you want:

```
'Some line e.g., when people do something.'
```